# server side image conversion efficiency

Tags: image-processing, svg, imagemagick

What would be the most efficient way to convert SVG to PNG, server side?

At the moment I have some SVG content which is posted to PHP, then written to disk before calling Imagemagick's convert command.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access, you could look into using [rsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/docs/man-rsvg.php) (fast!) or [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html); otherwise, using ImageMagick is about the only option accessible to you.

Benchmarks can be found @ [mediawiki.org/wiki/SVG_benchmarks#Benchmark](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/SVG_benchmarks#Benchmark)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not sure if the Inkscape benchmarks were taken with a full relaunch between each processed file. Note that it has a commandline batchmode that can process any number of files in one go. That can be used to avoid a full app relaunch per file.